# AKS in paired regions, do the VNets have to be peered between regions?

Tags: azure-aks

we have an AKS cluster which has Postgres deployed in it. We want to deploy the same cluster to a paired region, but the two Postgres servers must be able to see and talk to each other. Do we need to implement peering between the VNets in each region in order for the two Postgres pods in AKS to see and talk to each other?

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

As you have already found an answer in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/524788/aks-communications-across-regions-and-vnet-peering.html). Posting the same here for Stack Community reference. Thank you [**Srijit Bose**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16169604/srijit-bose-msft) for the answer in Q&A.

**Scenario:**

> AKS cluster A with Postgres workload instance A is deployed in Azure
> region A and AKS cluster B with Postgres workload instance B is
> deployed in Azure region B. Postgres workload instance A and Postgres
> workload instance B should to be able to talk to each other.

**Possible Solutions:**

- Postgres A and Postgres B can communicate with each other over the public internet if you are exposing both of them using Services of `ServiceType LoadBalancer` or a public Ingress.

**Reference:**
[Concepts - Networking in Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS) - Azure Kubernetes Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network)

- If you want Postgres A and Postgres B to talk over a secure tunnel on the internet, you can connect the Virtual Networks of the two AKS clusters using Azure VNet-to-VNet VPN

**Reference:**
[Configure a VNet-to-VNet VPN gateway connection: Azure portal - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal)

- If you want Postgres A and postgres B to talk to each other over private internet, you can peer the Virtual Networks of the two AKS clusters.

**Reference:**
[Azure Virtual Network peering | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview)

You can also refer to [AKS Baseline for multi-region clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/containers/aks-multi-region/aks-multi-cluster) and [Network Topology in Baseline architecture for AKS Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/containers/aks/secure-baseline-aks#network-topology).

> Since postgres doesn't support active/active, we are going to use a
> trigger-based tool so that if Posgress in AKS A has a write, that
> write is propogated to AKS B. I want to not use the Internet and would
> prefer to peer the VNETs. If I peer the VNETs, I assume AKS A can
> speak to AKS B and we can use the private IPs of the pods to
> communicate provided that the ports are exposed on both AKS clusters.
> We are using CNI for networking.

As you are using Azure CNI as the network plugin for the AKS clusters, the Pod IPs are going to be assigned from the AKS VNET/subnets. If the two Virtual Networks are peered, then please ensure that the Effective Inbound Network Security Group rules associated with either subnet in the two virtual networks, must allow traffic to `ports: Any` from `source: VirtualNetwork` to `destination: Any on the requisite protocol(s)`.